# Fluent mapping and relation table with Active flag

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a relation table but with one additional column `Active bit not null`

I fail to understand how I should map with in EF6, I have 3 tables, `Foo`, `Bar` and `FooBar` where FooBar is the relation table

```
FooBar {
   FooId: int (Key and FK)
   BarId: int (Key and FK)
   Active: bit
}
```

Foo entity

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Id { get;set; }  
   public ICollection<FooBar> Bars { get; set; } 
   ...
}
```

FooBar entity

```
public class FooBar
{
   public Foo Foo { get;set; }  
   public Bar Bar { get;set; }  
   public bool Active { get;set; }
}
```

And now to the **problem**, EF configuration
FooBar config

```
public class FooBarConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FooBar>
    {
        public FooBarConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(fb => new[] {fb.Foo.Id, pv.Bar.Id}); //Is this correct?

            Property(pv => pv.Active);

            ToTable("ProductVehicle");
        }
    }
```

I have  no clue have the Foo config should be like, so im stuck, tried something like

```
public class FooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);          

        HasMany(f => f.Bars)
            .WithRequired(f => p.Foo)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.Foo.Id);

        ToTable("Foo");
    }
}
```

I get

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The properties expression 'f => f.Foo.Id'
>   is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't =>
>   t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying
>   multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new {
>   t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With {
>   t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

I i change FooConfig too

```
HasMany(f => p.Bars)
    .WithRequired(fb => fb.Foo)
    .Map(map => map.MapKey("FooId"));
```

I get a little longer, now it fails on FooBar config with

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The properties expression 'fb => new []
>   {fb.Foo.Id, fb.Bar.Id}' is not valid. The expression should
>   represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t)
>   t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous
>   type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net:
>   'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

edit: I ended up with this solution to get it a little more domaindriven,

```
public class ProductVehicle
{
    private Product _product;
    private Vehicle _vehicle;
    internal int ProductId { get; set; }
    internal int VehicleId { get; set; }

    public Product Product
    {
        get { return _product; }
        set
        {
            _product = value;
            ProductId = value.Id;
        }
    }

    public Vehicle Vehicle
    {
        get { return _vehicle; }
        set
        {
            _vehicle = value;
            VehicleId = value.Id;
        }
    }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a property of a navigation property as a key or as a foreign key, which isn't allowed. The join table itself (and the corresponding entity) should have the columns (and properties) for the foreign keys and composite primary key

#### Add the foreign keys to your join table model which also serve as the composite primary key

```
public class FooBar
{
   public int FooId { get; set; }
   public int BarId { get; set; }

   public Foo Foo { get;set; }  
   public Bar Bar { get;set; }  
   public bool Active { get;set; }
}
```

#### Configure those foreign keys as primary keys

```
public class FooBarConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FooBar>
{
    public FooBarConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(fb => new[] { fb.FooId, fb.BarId });

        // A reversed version could be placed in the Foo configuration
        // But only one is necessary
        HasRequired(fb => fb.Foo)
            .WithMany(fb => fb.Bars)
            .HasForeignKey(fb => fb.FooId);

        // Something similar for relationship with Bar

        Property(pv => pv.Active);

        ToTable("ProductVehicle"); // You mean FooBar right? ;)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ops, production name slipped through :D yeah this is what I have sofar. But it will be a bit ugly when updating from UI. I'm not 100% finished with this user story, if I have  no problems I will mark as answer

Comment: I ended up with a little different solution to make it more domain driven, see edit

Answer (score 2):

you need to add a property to FooBar, say FooId:

```
public class FooBar
{ 
...
   public int FooId { get { return Foo.Id;}}
}
```

and then change the code to read:

```
 HasMany(f => f.Bars)
        .WithRequired(f => p.Foo)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.FooId);
```